# Separate round cube in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

Youtube has a good example of creating a dice. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GagyfOcJHQ)*(2:38-13:50)*. How was the separation of the round cube?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear about what you actually want to know?

Comment: That Penfinity is a devil. He's good, but he likes to rub it in by concealing half of what he's up to. You can admire his virtuosity; maybe not so much his desire to teach. Learning from his videos involves frame-by frame inspection, and a fair amount of reverse-engineering.

Comment: yes he doesn't tell a lot about the shortcuts and tools he uses   ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, if you're talking about what he's doing a 3:10 (not sure though):

- Select the 3 edges of a corner, then press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (*select similar*) > *Length*, it will select all the edge with a similar length, in this case the edges separating the 6 faces of the cube.
- Now to separate these 6 faces, just press <kbd>V</kbd> (rip).
- As *Pivot Center*, choose *Individual Origins*, now when you scale down the whole mesh, each face will scale individually.
- Note that his cube is shrinkwraped to another round cube, which makes the individual faces follow a round profile.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Everything turned out beautifully and correctly, I did not know the operation RIP and confused it with a separate ...